# spacing in tree diagram

Tags: css, html, tree, geometry

[image: image of how my tree looks now]

edit: The image above is how the tree looks now. I would like to make it look like a normal tree where each parent is between its two children.

How do I calculate the margin to put around each block in the included image so that each parent is directly above and between it's two children?

I am trying to display a representation of a binary tree in HTML where each generation has its own div (separated by dashes). Each block is also its own div inside the generation divs that is set to `display: inline-block;`. The blocks are centered because each generation has `text-align: center;`

In order to align each parent between its two children, the spacing is different from generation to generation. How do I calculate this spacing? Also, it there an easier way to do this in HTML than just adding padding to the individual blocks like i'm doing now?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks fairly straightforward if a little fiddly to get right.  What have you tried so far, where are you stuck ?

Comment: I'm mostly stuck on the math. I'm not sure how much spacing should be in between each block so that it is aligned between its children. I know that the spacing must be some function of the number of blocks the row but I don't know how to calculate this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start your layout at the bottom row with whatever inter-block spacing you want.  The x-coordinate of the parent of 2 sibling blocks is the mean of the x-coordinates of the children.  This expresses the intent of your thinking much better than trying to work out the spacing level-by-level. Spend some time with pencil and paper figuring it out.